# Why do we use dummy@google.com in C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have been playing with Google C2DM, and managed to successfully get the push working. When I was trying to understand the code,
The C2DMReceiver class of Google C2DM, has a constructor in it, which has the following lines

```
public C2DMReceiver() {
        // Email address currently not used by the C2DM Messaging framework

        super("dummy@google.com");
    }
```

My question is, what does this email denote? Is it the same if I remove the super statement?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Nithin

Comment: Reply an answer, and then say that!

Comment: replied :P even though i didn't really see any point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is because Google uses that email address only as a reporting mechanism and doesn't really use it for anything else. So for now you can just supply anything and it will still work but it is advised to use the email address you used to register for the push notification services.

Comment: So I can use the same gmail address there too? Are you sure it doesn't matter anywhere?

Comment: @nithinreddy Yes pretty sure.